# I can't solve my <identifier> expected error, and dont know why

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Ok, so im super, extra, brand new to java coding, but im slowly getting all the terms. But the real issue is this error. I'm trying to do a little coding snippet that, when started, will open a batch file (i'm much more experienced with them). I searched very much for answers, but nothing solved it, so i had o post about my specific situation.

This is said code:

```
 public class Startbat {
 public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start hello.bat");
        }
    catch (IOException) {
        System.out.println ("Something is wrong here...");
        }
 }
}
```

and when i try to javac it, i get this:

```
C:\Users\Owner>javac -g "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\codes\codes\Startbat.java"
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\codes\codes\Startbat.java:6: error: <identifier> expected

            catch (IOException) {
                              ^
1 error
```

I have found that the error I get is about the catch line/block not being in a method, when I have definitely made sure that it IS within the main.

I had a few error with the exception there, but i guess i solved it. i don't know what the exception would have been ((meaning how would that IOException occur from the runtime.exec stuff) meaning does that mean it won't start the batch file if it does get to work?).

Any help would be appreciated, even if its just "This is impossible to do"

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a variable for the exception, so you can use it later, for example...

```
catch (IOException exp) {
```

You should also consider printing the exception, at least to the console if not some kind of logger...

```
catch (IOException exp) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    //...
```

This will make it easier to track down potential problems if/when they occur.

As a side note, you really should use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec`, apart from anything else, it provides better management of the output streams and agruments that contain spaces...

Comment: ok, but i have just, all the sudden looked at this differently and found that the compiler is seeing the runtime.exec as an IO exception, which im not sure why. I've tried to do a few things, but it just seems that it doesnt like that line. And that try/catch code is all because of tha error, so i think if i can fix the IO error, i dont the erroneous try/catch code.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` throws an `IOException`, so you either need to catch it, or re-throw it...

Comment: Oh my god, i finally understand. I had to import the java.io.* files, add the variable, which i now know can just be ignored and the rest of the file can be executed, and i also had issues because no one told me that i had to do /cd (folder path of class) to do "java -cp . Startbat". Thank you soo much, I could hug you through the monitor if i could! (hug hug)